# App which allows me to comment *and* to write free-hand on PDFs

Tags: macos, pdf, software-recommendation

I'm looking for a PDF editing app with the following requirements that runs on macOS 11.6.5 (Big Sur):

- highlight text, different colors
- add comments/notes, same as above
- write and draw free-hand
- (nice-to-have, but not a strict requirement) free

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Try goodnotes..

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @nohillside nothing, but I googled a bit and I found these two apps: https://highlightsapp.net/ https://pdf.wondershare.com/how-to/add-comments-to-pdf.html however, they don't seem to support freehand note-taking

Comment: How exactly would you do freehand writing (tool-wise), I see neither a trackbad nor a mouse as a useful solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might surprise you, but the built-in **Preview** app has all of these features.

Here's an Apple Support article that describes all of the markup tools: https://support.apple.com/guide/preview/annotate-a-pdf-prvw11580/mac

Comment: This indeed surprises me. I see that I can add comments & notes, but what about freehand writing? Notes are written like regular text, using the selected font.